# Link rel="canonical": Should different user guide versions use the same canonical url?

Tags: html, seo, documentation, canonical-link, user-guide

Should 2 different versions of a user guide use **a different canonical URL**?

Documentation version `1.1.0.Final`:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://docs.foo.org/1.1.0.Final/index.html">
```

Documentation version `1.2.0.Final`:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://docs.foo.org/1.2.0.Final/index.html">
```

---

Or should 2 different versions of a user guide use **the same canonical URL**?

Documentation version `1.1.0.Final`:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://docs.foo.org/latestFinal/index.html">
```

Documentation version `1.2.0.Final`:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://docs.foo.org/latestFinal/index.html">
```

Comment: Related question on [webmasters.se]: [*How to correctly mark up different versions of the same document which are non-canonical*](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/99867/17633)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [*The Canonical Link Relation* from RFC 6596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-3), the `canonical` link type may only be used for URIs that identify content that is

- **duplicative**, or
- a **superset**.

As this is not necessarily the case for different versions of the user guide (because features might be added/removed/changed), the `canonical` link type must **not** be used to always point to the latest version. If you want to use `canonical`, it would have to be self-referential.

Comment: Is there any google-approved way to make Google prefer the latestFinal url for search results?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet: Not that I know of. For example, a signal like the publication date might help (if Google is sophisticated enough), but this would be a SEO subject (which is off-topic on Stack Overflow). The Webmasters SE question I linked in the comment, [*How to correctly mark up different versions of the same document which are non-canonical*](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/99867/17633), is about this case.

Comment: Disagree with this. It is used for _essentially_ duplicated documentation, not an exact duplication. The diff between each version is usually miniscule. You'll also be penalised for the duplicated content.

Comment: @oligofren: The RFC doesn’t speak of "essentially" duplicated. *Duplicative* doesn’t have to mean byte-for-byte identical, of course (content might be rearranged, typos be fixed etc.). The idea is that you may ignore the current page if it points to a different canonical URL -- but in OP’s case a consumer (tools, bots, humans, …) should *not* ignore the page, as it may document a feature that is e.g. no longer part of newer pages (or changed etc.).