# How to favour a specific version of a website for SEO?

Tags: url, seo

I am running a website that contains documentation for an open-source project of mine. The various pages are available in different versions, which you can differ by their url schema:

- `/1.0/some-topic`
- `/2.0/some-topc`
- `/latest/some-topic`

This works perfectly fine, but I'm running into problems with Google: If you search the web for *some topic*, you get all the different versions as results. While this is basically fine, it would make more sense to show the newest ones first. Unfortunately, older pages get ranked better than newer ones.

Is there any way I can give a hint to search engines to favour the newer versions of those pages over the older ones? Is there a clean, official way for this?

Comment: Related (not duplicate): [Link rel=“canonical”: Should different user guide versions use the same canonical url?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39913212/1591669)

Comment: [webmasters.se] questions about the same topic: [How to correctly mark up different versions of the same document which are non-canonical](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/99867/17633)